# Get just the staus of autosys (main) job/box

Tags: unix, autosys

I have a main autosys box (first_start_main_job)that has 2 different sub box.

When I enter `autorep -j  first_start_main_job -d` I get something like:

```
JOb Name | Last Start | Last Run | ST | RUN | Pri/Xtx
first_start_main_job | some_time | some_time | SU | some_text
first_start_sub_job | some_time | some_time | SU | some_text
second_start_sub_job | some_time | some_time | SU | some_text
```

I just want ST(status) of first_start_main_job and store that in a variable.

Please let me know how to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the print level switch `-L`, with level 0, (zero) to list only the outermost box. Then use your favorite script tool to get and store the ST value.

For example:

```
autorep -J main_job_box -d -L0
```

`man autorep` from a AutoSys command prompt will give you more information if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding up to above posted answer.
To get the Status of Job in a variable we can filter out the status using awk.
e.g.

```
autorep -J first_start_main_job -d -L0 | awk '/SU /{print $6}'
```

It will check for the first line and if it contains "SU ", than the status will be printed.